# What's the correct way to use Thinking Sphinx scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to create a TS scope as follows:

```
include ThinkingSphinx::Scopes
sphinx_scope(:status_approved) {
      {:conditions => {:status => "approved"}}
    }
default_sphinx_scope :status_approved
```

My indice file is:

```
indexes name, status
has user_id, created_at
```

Two questions:

1. Does field *status* needs to be defined as an index in order for the conditions string filter to work? Seems like I get a *no field in schema* query error if I do not do that.
2. If it is required to define as part of the indexes, then whenever someone updated the *status* field, it will not show in the results until the next reindex occurs. Is this the only way to use a string filtering TS scope? Or is there a better way to do this?

I'm using Rails 3.2.16 and TS 3.0.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Sphinx scopes are for your Sphinx searches, so yes, you'll need status as a field in your index definition if you're using it in a Sphinx scope.
2. If you want your Sphinx index data up-to-date as quickly as possible, you may want to investigate using delta indices (perhaps using [Delayed Job](https://github.com/pat/ts-delayed-delta/) or [Sidekiq](https://github.com/pat/ts-sidekiq-delta/), to remove it from your web processes). Or, you could use Sphinx's [real-time indices](http://freelancing-gods.com/posts/rewriting_thinking_sphinx_introducing_realtime_indices) instead.

Comment: Pat, you beat me by 15 minutes with your post, while i was still typing. :-) I'll accept your answer since you offered me more options to investigate. Thks

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own questions after further research:

1. I have search through the documentation but have not found any specific reference to this. I may have missed it. However by trial and errors , I found that if I want to use the string filter method, I have to add the field to the indexes. If not, it will complain that the field is not found in the schema.
2. There is a 'new' feature introduced to TS called *Realtime Indices* which apparently addresses this issue. This was mentioned in the author's blog http://freelancing-gods.com/ I have not tried it. In any case, I have taken a different route which did away using the default scope and use the filtering in the indices instead. In my index file, i now have:

   ```
   indexes name, status
   has user_id, created_at
   where "status = 'approved'"
   ```

And I no longer need to define the default scope in my model as such. This will still require periodic reindexing in any case.